# How do I take the red out of an image using Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I've just used this code to keep just the red in an image:

```
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(imread(filename));
hPlane = 360.*hsvImage(:,:,1);
sPlane = hsvImage(:,:,2);
nonRedIndex = (hPlane > 25) & (hPlane < 340);
sPlane(nonRedIndex) = 0;
hsvImage(:,:,2) = sPlane;
rgbImage = hsv2rgb(hsvImage);
```

Here's a set of my images with only red:

[image: Only red]

Now I'm trying to change it so it takes out the red, like so:

```
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(imread(filename));
hPlane = 360.*hsvImage(:,:,1);
sPlane = hsvImage(:,:,2);
nonRedIndex = (hPlane < 25) & (hPlane > 340);
sPlane(nonRedIndex) = 0;
hsvImage(:,:,2) = sPlane;
rgbImage = hsv2rgb(hsvImage);
```

But for some reason the red stays in the image. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Here's the images that should have none of the red in the first image:

[image: No Red]

It should just the opposite from the other image, right? I'm not sure why it isn't getting rid of the red.

Comment: please add some example images to make your question more clear,

Comment: @Shai I've added some pictures!

Comment: `nonRedIndex = (hPlane < 25) & (hPlane > 340);`. What's this? It will never be true.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - the hue value range for pure red is 0, but here a circular range from 340 - 25 is being used to capture more 'red' hues.  The boolean operator should be an OR rather than an AND, though (attn @user3457834!).

Comment: @Staus - That was absolutely my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Staus Yes, I know that. Hue is circular, therefore `0` and `360` are same and they are pure red. However, the condition would have never been true.